# keyboard hook in windows C++ or what?

Tags: windows, keyboard, message, hook

I wish to build my own application which can send keyboard commands(messages) to the Windows OS.

For example when I press the combination ctrl+shift+n, I wish to launch the notepad.exe . How can I do that? Do you have some advice for me about the concept used.

I've read that is possible when are used keyboard hooks? That's the only way? Do you know a free and open-source application which does this as simple is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your particular example can be done without any programming at all, by right clicking on Notepad, selecting Properties, and setting the "hot key" (various Windows versions might call it by a different name) to Ctrl+Shift+N.

If you still would like to write a program to do this, have a look at the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API function.

Comment: ty, but i really wish to write the program :)

Answer (score 3):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a free, open-source utility for Windows.
You can automate many tasks with the above utility, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Things to bear in mind:

A system-wide keyboard hook requires the writing of a DLL. There's example keyboard hook code on my website [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip69.htm).

Hooks cannot be installed from a low to a high integrity level application in Vista and Windows 7/8/10. So there's no guarantee your hook will work, depending upon what the foreground application is when the key gets hit.

As Greg pointed out, a lot of the time, RegisterHotKey is a much simpler solution for this problem.