# Creating a Process in the background that will listen to keyboard

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have a project that runs in the background in a different process, I want it to be able to react to keyboard everywhere, for example I run the project, and afterwards I do other stuff in the computer such as browsing, facebook, watching movies etc.., and every time I press F9 I want my project to show up. Same as how you press a combination of keys to invoke Babylon... I want to implement it in C#, I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7730869/932418

Comment: You'll be wanting something other than F9. Everybody that uses programs that use the F9 shortcut will hate your app. Otherwise RegisterHotKey is your guy.

Answer (score 9):

You can register a hotkey with the [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function. You can see an example of its usage from C# [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/).

Comment: This is precisely what the Hotkey APIs were intended for. Though taking over F9 might be a bad idea if someone other than yourself is going to use this app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a system-wide keyboard hook, check here for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764434/559144

[How do I grab events for all applications? An example system-wide hook.](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip69.htm)

Comment: It's a possible solution, but it's a bit like using a cannon to kill a mosquito. :)

Comment: so, whats your solution?